# Reassigning the %%subscription_center_url%% location

Tags: marketing-cloud, cloudpage

We have built a custom subscription center and I can't seem to find a place to replace the out of box preference center.  I recall seeing somewhere that I need to put in a support case.

Can anyone verify?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The ideal situation would be to contact support to have this done. You could also Add this script to over write it.

```
%%[If 1 = 0 then]%% %%subscription_center_url%% %%[endif]%%
```

Be fully aware of CAN-SPAN obligations as you apply this.

Comment: We're still in the IP warming phase - `medium` reputation with Google.  Think it's a good idea to go support route to circumvent any algorithm they have that will flag an ampscript over-ride?